# Explain foreach loop in php

Tags: php

Can somebody explain foreach loop in php? I know so many answers are available but am not able to understand what the actual mean and use of this.please explain in simple language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Go [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, foreach loop is meant to loop through arrays. By setting an array elements, on every single pass through them foreach loop asigns next element value in the array to $value, i.e. it takes the value of an array element and passes it to a 'basket' calld $value, which in turn, when invoked, it takes that value from the basket and prints it on the screen.